# Which Tab Control does Visual Studio 2008 use?

Tags: c#

Which tab control does VS 2008 use and is it possible to reference and use it in C# projects?  I have not been able to find anything on the web about it, but admittedly "VS2008 Tab Control" is a bit generic.

It's a great tab control and I would love to leverage it in my own projects.

Comment: What do you mean with TabControl? There is just one...

Comment: Visual Studio uses a Tab Control to display it's text editors.  I had hoped that I could just use the same one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wonderful one on SourceForge: WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking (or DockingSuite). <strike>Sorry no link (yet).</strike>

#### Update

Sourceforge link: [Dock Panel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/)
Sample Project on CodeProject: [A Visual Studio 2005-like Interface](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/DockPanelSkin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The VS2008's tabbed MDI control is not available but there are some third party components that are quite good at it. [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/mdi.xml) has one.

Further reading about tabbed MDI can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabbed_document_interface)

Answer (score 0):

The document editing area in Visual Studio 2008 is more than just a tab control. It allows you to place documents in a vertical or horizontal stack. There is nothing similar provided as part of the standard window forms controls. You need to either create your own control or buy a third party control that performs the same action.

Comment: My own company, www.componentfactory.com provides a control like this called KryptonWorkspace.